# Book with gender-disguised male magician, forbidden language, one character can talk to horses

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a book we read back in the early 2000s (2003?) which had a male magician who disguised himself as a woman and was travelling on a quest with two other women, who were unaware of his real gender. Other remembered details follow:

- probably written in the 1990s
- the male mage (while disguised a woman) was involved in a sexual encounter/orgy with a stable boy, and his secret identity was, er, noticed
- high fantasy, felt inspired by Lord of the Rings
- there was a language which at least one character knew, which was forbidden to speak out loud (similar to the reluctance of people in LoTR to speak out loud the language of Mordor)
- one character might have been able to talk to horses
- the cover of the book was purple
- don't remember if the author was male or female.
- possibly a young adult book

Thanks in advance for any hints and help.

Comment: This rings a vague bell. Could it have been one of LE Modesitt's Recluce books?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a Mercedes Lackey book.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like [*The Innkeeper's Song*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11938.The_Innkeeper_s_Song?from_search=true) (1993) by Peter S. Beagle, mainly by dint of one of the characters being magically disguised as a woman. There is also a stableboy in the story.

Here is the logline: "Three powerful women (each with her own secret past), a stable boy, a weaver's son, and an innkeeper set in motion a series of events that brings each of them face to face with the forces of magic and the workings of fate."

[image: Three women, one black, one white with black hair dressed in white, and one hooded. Cover art by Palencar.]